# How to update big tables on google Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

What is the best practice for "updating" tables on Google BigQuery?

I get massive batch files that need to be loaded every hour.

Some of the records in the batch files contain records that need to replace the old ones in the big target table.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an id for each record, you can merge the new table and old table like this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM [oldtable] WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM [newtable])),
  (SELECT * FROM [newtable])
```

Comment: thanks! but what you do when the key contains more than one column?
how do you deal when you need to update "partitions" when you have multi tables didded by the business date and not the insertion date?

Comment: Depends. How do you tell it's a new row or an update if you don't have an id?

Comment: i have id, the key is contains more than one field.

Comment: i have id, the key is contains more than one field.
the question is, how do you deal with new increment table that contain s new row + old rows that need to be update. but the DWH (destination table) is split by business days. what means that several tables need to be update.

Comment: but when i'm have timestamp field in this union query i facing usec bug

Comment: it's seems that big query generate join when using NOT IN, the problem that it's not generate join each when it's needed..and for big tables compare, this query failed..